# How to make gcc linker output section size at command line?

Tags: c++, gcc

I program for MCUs. The size of code and data is important and I need to know the size of these section after compiling. I've known how to get these imformation. Just define

```
__text_size = SIZEOF(.text);
```

in the linker script file, and than I can get the value of it in the map file output by the linker. (the ".text" is a section defined in my linker script file).
  However, I hate to open the map file and search for the __text_size every time after compiling and linking. 
  Is there any way to tell the linker to output the size of a section at command line? The Keil, for example, always output the code, rodata, data and zi-data size after compiling.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can use the [size](http://linux.die.net/man/1/size) utility:

> $size test
>   text       data     bss     dec     hex filename
>     1153 504       24    1681     691 test

Comment: sorry, I'm not quite familiar with gcc. Could you explain it with more details ? Where should I put the size command?